# Unable to run spark-testing-base test with Spark v3.2.1

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, scalatest

I was trying to run Spark UT with spark-testing-base and scalatest, getting following exceptions:

```
[error] sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected instance not static method org.scalatest.Assertions.assertionsHelper()Lorg/scalatest/Assertions$AssertionsHelper;
[error]     at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.StreamingSuiteBase.verifyOutput(StreamingSuiteBase.scala:77)
[error]     at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.StreamingSuiteBase.verifyOutput$(StreamingSuiteBase.scala:61)
[error]     at com.central.spark.aggregation.streaming.BaseAggregatorSuite.verifyOutput(BaseAggregatorSuite.scala:23)
[error]     at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.StreamingSuiteBase.$anonfun$testOperation$1(StreamingSuiteBase.scala:162)
[error]     at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.StreamingSuiteBase.$anonfun$testOperation$1$adapted(StreamingSuiteBase.scala:158)
[error]     at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.StreamingSuiteCommon.withOutputAndStreamingContext(StreamingSuiteCommon.scala:122)
[error]     at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.StreamingSuiteCommon.withOutputAndStreamingContext$(StreamingSuiteCommon.scala:114)
[error]     at com.central.spark.aggregation.streaming.BaseAggregatorSuite.withOutputAndStreamingContext(BaseAggregatorSuite.scala:23)
[error]     at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.StreamingSuiteBase.testOperation(StreamingSuiteBase.scala:158)
[error]     at com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.StreamingSuiteBase.testOperation$(StreamingSuiteBase.scala:149)
[error]     at com.central.spark.aggregation.streaming.BaseAggregatorSuite.testOperation(BaseAggregatorSuite.scala:23)
[error]     at com.central.spark.aggregation.streaming.BaseAggregatorSuite.$anonfun$new$1(BaseAggregatorSuite.scala:89)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23) (truc)
```

The dependency and their versions are:

```
  lazy val coreTestDeps = Seq(
    "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % 1.10.19 % "test",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % 3.2.12 % "it,test",
    "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % 2.3 % "test",
    "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % 3.7.0-M11 % "it,test",
    "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % 3.7.0-M11 % "it,test",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % 3.2.1 % "provided" classifier "tests",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % 3.2.1 % "provided" classifier "tests",
    "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "3.2.0_1.1.1" % "test",
    "org.elasticsearch.client" % "elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client" % 7.9.3 % "it,test"
  )
```

I tried downgrading the `org.scalatest` to `3.0.9` and other version, But it is not working. Have followings in build.sbt as suggested at [spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base) repo:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.15",
Test / parallelExecution := false,
Test / fork := true,
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MetaspaceSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")
```

Any suggestion on how should i proceed?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: BEWARE: [json4s is vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)